# Do I need to update the standard deviation into GARCH for the next step conditional variance predict?

Tags: value-at-risk

I need to compare two garch models, I try to do that by Value at Risk. In general, if I have an initial conditional variance, for example, h1, then I can predict the next N days conditional variance by a known garch model, whereafter, I calculate the VaR based on these conditional variance and make the comparison between two garch models, simply saying, to see how many times the daily return exceeds the VaR. My question is that: do I need to make a one day ahead predict based on the standard deviation from real data (get it by high frequency method) each time? or just make N days prediction based on the initial h1. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what criterion you want to compare the models: on their one-step ahead prediction error with expanding window (updating the model on each step) or with an in-sample (estimation) period and out-of-sample (validation) period. It's a design decision.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Paul. I am do the test in-sample but not make the decision for future, then in your words, it is unnecessary to update each step?

Comment: If I understand correctly you only want to compare both GARCH models in-sample? In that case, it would make sense to simply calculate variance for the VaR estimate of the full in-sample period as well. For out-of-sample, it would make more sense to iteratively update your VaR distribution with an expanding window.

Comment: Yes,  I just need to make a comparison. One more thing, if it is OK for you, @Jean-Paul. I have BIC for model A and model B and it shows A is better fit. But in the VaR test, the case is converse, is that reasonable?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely how exactly you are performing this VaR test? Because VaR will simply give you a certain threshold for each moment in time. If one model crosses this threshold more often than another model, we can not infer from this that one model is worse than the other model. After all, you are trying to *estimate* volatility. Because *volatility* is **unobserved**, comparing it to crossing the VaR threshold is not very informative. Instead, VaR is meant to estimate a risk factor based on historically realised *returns*, not volatility.

Comment: I just count the times the return cross the threshold(VaR, alpha = 5%) and then divide the total observation number to get a probability p. If the more p is close to 5%, the more the model accurate. I am not sure this method works.

Comment: There is a flaw in your thinking here: GARCH is meant to estimate volatility. Eventhough it also gives an expression for the mean, you shouldn't compare two GARCH models based on their mean estimates. And by applying the VaR test like described, that is effectively what you are doing.

Comment: No, @Jean-Paul, I have minus the mean of the time series preliminarily, so they are two models to describe the volatility. So my method is like Kupiec test but just to calculate the violated rate.